# keyboard shortcut for vim

Tags: linux, shell, vim

please could someone give me a list of some keyboard shortcut editor vim in particular to save and close?

I try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> orders or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> but no success until a present

Comment: `vim` is all about keyboard shortcuts. See [Vim Book](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/doc/book/vimbook-OPL.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

`ZZ` does save and close

`ZQ` does close without save

both work in normal mode.

Answer (score 3):

For quiting vim shell,

- hit `ESC` and
- then `:q` for quit without any changes.
- `Enter`

Some commands are here:

```
:q[uit]     Quit Vim. This fails when changes have been made.
:q[uit]!    Quit without writing.
:cq[uit]    Quit always, without writing.
:wq         Write the current file and exit.
:wq!        Write the current file and exit always.
:wq         {file}  Write to {file}. Exit if not editing the last
:wq!        {file}  Write to {file} and exit always.
:[range]wq[!]   [file] Same as above, but only write the lines in   [range].
ZZ          Write current file, if modified, and exit.
ZQ          Quit current file and exit (same as ":q!").
```

For quick overview : [Vim commands](https://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html)

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is:

- Hit ESC
- type :wq [name of the file, if it's a new file]
- type Enter

The long answer, well, it's really long...

Answer (score 2):

Some commands in this guide start with a colon: pressing it will display the command prompt where the subsequent command is written.

Commands without a colon are more like hotkeys - they can be used in the Vim default mode (which is the mode Vim starts in).

Commands written in CAPITAL LETTERS are specific keys: for example, ESC means the escape key on your keyboard.

All commands in Vim are case-sensitive.

**EXITING VIM**

To quit, discarding any changes you might have made:

```
:q!
```

*Memorize: quit dammit!*

To quit, saving any changes you've made:

```
:wq
```

*Memorize: write to disk and quit*

**NAVIGATING THE EDITOR**

To move around the currently open file, use your arrow keys.

To move to line 285:

```
:285
```

To search for the word import:

```
/import
```

**EDITING TEXT**

To start inserting text on the current cursor location:

```
i
```

*Memorize: insert*

To start inserting at the end of the current line:

```
A
```

*Memorize: Append*

To exit insert mode, and return to the default mode:

```
ESC
```

**SELECTING TEXT**

To start selecting, enter the visual mode:

```
v
```

*Memorize: visual*

Select text by moving with your arrow keys.

To exit visual mode:

```
ESC
```

**COPY, CUT, PASTE**

To copy the current selection into the buffer (think of it as a clipboard):

```
y
```

*Memorize: yank*

To cut the current selection:

```
d
```

*Memorize: delete*

To copy the current line into the buffer:

```
yy
```

*Memorize: yank yank*

To copy 3 lines including the current line into the buffer:

```
3yy
```

To cut the current line and place it into the buffer:

```
dd
```

*Memorize: delete delete*

To cut 5 lines including the current line:

```
5dd
```

To paste the buffer before the current line:

```
P
```

*Note: Uppercase P*

To paste the buffer after the current line:

```
p
```

**UNDO AND REDO**

To undo the last change:

```
u
```

*Memorize: uh-oh :)*

To redo the last change you just undid:

```
CTRL + R
```

To see the number of changes:

```
:undolist
```

To undo the last two changes:

```
2u
```

The Vim multi-level undo tree is very powerful. [Read more about it here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_32.html).

**OPENING FILES**

To open the file index.html instead of the current one:

```
:edit index.html
```

**SAVING FILES**

To save the file you're currently editing:

```
:w
```

*Memorize: write to disk*

To save the file with a different name, here `changes.txt` (ie. Save As):

```
:w changes.txt
```

**Searching and Replacing**

To search and replace all occurences of a string in the file:

```
:%s/typo/corrected/g
```

To search and replace, but prompt before replacing:

```
:%s/typo/corrected/gc
```

*Memorize: confirm*
Syntax highlighting and Indentation

Turn on syntax highlighting:

```
:syntax on
```

Enable automatic indentation:

```
:set autoindent
```

Increase indentation on multiple lines by selecting them in visual mode, and pressing:

```
>
```

Working with multiple files

**TABS**

To open server.py in a new tab:

```
:tabe server.py
```

*Memorize: tab edit*

To move to the next tab on the right:

```
:tabn
```

*Memorize: tab next*

To move to the previous tab on the left:

```
:tabp
```

*Memorize: tab previous*

To close a tab, move to it and use `:q` or `:wq` as you would normally.

**SPLIT VIEW**

To open templates/base.html in a vertical split screen:

```
:vs templates/base.html
```

*Memorize: vertical split*

To open shared.js in a horizontal split screen:

```
:sp shared.js
```

*Memorize: the 'default' horizontal split*

To move between split screens:

```
CTRL + W + ARROW KEYS
```

To close a split screen, move to it and use `:q` or `:wq` as you would normally.

More information [at here](https://getintodevops.com/blog/how-the-hell-do-i-exit-a-beginners-guide-to-vim).

Answer (score 0):

Those are very basic questions. It is better for you to start vim in tutorial mode, like this:

```
$ vimtutor
```